# boolean logic - comparing three booleans

Tags: java, boolean

I'm trying to construct a method to answer the below question. However I'm having a bit of trouble. Can someone assist me with this logic?

Write a static method odd() that takes three boolean inputs and returns true if an odd number of inputs are true, and false otherwise.

```
public boolean odd(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c)
    {   
        if((a && b) && (b && c) && (a && c))
            return true;
        if((a && b) && (b && c) || (a && b) && (a && c))
            return false;
         return false;
    }
```

Comment: What is the trouble?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I'm not confident that my algoritm covers all the edge cases.

Comment: There are only 8 possible input combinations.  Just test them all.

Comment: @d_blk Well there's not an infinity of  cases. You can write a simple test that checks all the possibilites.

Comment: have you tried to test it ?

Comment: you can just xor the inputs together and return that.

Comment: That first condition is just a&&b&&c. So are both halves of the or statement below it. In short, what you have won't work, see ElliotF answer for a much better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do something like

```
public boolean odd(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c) {
    int count = 0;
    if (a) count++;
    if (b) count++;
    if (c) count++;
    return count % 2 != 0;   
}
```

If you really want to optimize it, I think you want something like

```
if (a || b || c) {
    if (a && b && c) return true;
    if (a) return !(b && c);
    if (b) return !c;
    return c;
}
return false;
```

Comment: That first code snippet is the correct one based on the spec, and _far_ more readable/understandable. Though, for a beginner level, it may be better to use `return (count == 1) || (count == 3);`. Still, a very good resonse.

Comment: I had to modify the return of the answer provide above.  return count % 2 != 0;

Answer (score 5):

```
public boolean odd(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c) {
    return a ^ b ^ c;  
}
```

`XOR` is also referred to as the odd function, meaning it will return `true` if an odd number of inputs are `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The function can be done in one line:

```
return (a&&b&&c) || (a && !b && !c ) || (!a && b && !c ) || (!a && !b && c );
```

If you need to do it with more than three inputs, I would suggest sending in an ArrayList to the function

```
 odd(ArrayList<Boolean> list)
 {
      int count = 0;
      for(Boolean b : list)
      {
           if(b.booleanValue()) count++;
      }
      return (count%2) == 1;
 }
```